# LAMP: slow query via PhpMyAdmin, fast via command line

Tags: mysql, php

I have a very strange problem - my server responds quite slowly even though it is basically unused: Apache seems to be less snappy than what I would expect and MySql responds to queries sent via PhpMyAdmin after at least 3/5 seconds even though this could be a simple SELECT and the table only has 10 records. The query itself is fast, but it takes a while before this is run. Interestingly the same query run throuh the command line is instantaneous without any delays.

I've been reading though everything I can find, but none of the solutions seem to apply to my case. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

It can be a resolution name problem.

Check how phpMyAdmin connects to mysql (ip, localhost, socket ?).

Answer (score 0):

if anyone coming from google, here you go. (sorry for the necro)

put these lines inside your mysql config's `[mysqld]` section to disable ipv6 lookup.

```
skip-host-cache
skip-name-resolve # specially this line
```

Src: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15436435/9720375